# MvvmCross V5 automatically navigate from Activity

Tags: android-fragments, xamarin, android-activity, navigation, mvvmcross

I want to have a single Activity, and have all my views as Fragments.

I have done this before by having my first view as an Activity and then immediate navigate to the Fragment. All the Fragments are placed in the content frame of the Activity view.

I did this by navigating to the Fragment from the OnCreate method of the Activity. This used to work, however with MvvmCross I can't get it to work.

I have a method on the Activity view model which performs the navigation

```
public async Task ShowMainView()
{
    await navigationService.Navigate<MainViewModel>();
}
```

This is called from OnCreateView in the activity.

```
ViewModel.ShowMainView.ContinueWith((task) =>
{
   // have now completed navigation
});
```

What I find is the MainViewModel constructor is called but nothing else?

Any ideas on why this doesn't work or how I should be doing this better.

Comment: An alternative would be to navigate directly to the fragment (via it's ViewModel) and let MvvmCross handle the navigation of the containing activity. Would that work for you?

Comment: On further investigation I think it is a problem with my fragment. I changed the code to navigate from a command with the same result. It's probably something simple.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was not with where I was doing the navigation from, it was a problem with the presenter being used. I found it was throwing an exception with the message

> Cannot create Fragment 'MainView'. Use the MvxAppCompatViewPresenter
>   when using Android Support Fragments.

I fixed the problem by setting the MvxAppCompatViewPresenter in the Setup.cs file in my Android project as shown below

```
        protected override IMvxAndroidViewPresenter CreateViewPresenter()
        {
            return new MvxAppCompatViewPresenter(this.AndroidViewAssemblies);
        }
```

Comment: You can also make use of inheriting `MvxAppCompatSetup` instead of `MvxAndroidSetup` for your `Setup.cs`. Which will use `MvxAppCompatViewPresenter` by default.